# Mobile version of Gmail on desktop Firefox

Tags: gmail, mobile, firefox

It would be useful to be able to check the mobile version of Gmail when my internet speed gets capped. I tried switching my user agent to iPhone 3, but this didn't display properly (appeared in a tiny box). Is there another way I can do this?

Note: I am using Firefox 3.68 on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried going to http://m.gmail.com to access the mobile site directly?

This takes me straight to the Gmail mobile interface with no user agent switching required.

Answer (score 4):

When signing into Gmail you can click `Load basic HTML` which loads an HTML version of the app, which is much smaller.

Answer (score 2):

In regard to your internet speed getting capped you could also take a look at [Opera for Mac OS X](http://www.opera.com/download/index.dml?platform=mac) with [Opera Turbo](http://www.opera.com/browser/tips/?feature=turbo) enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/x/a
(been using it for quite a long time; it's the most simple form of Gmail I have known, even better than the basic HTML view at https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/a)